# How to install elementary OS Openbox theme in Lubuntu 16.10?

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

I have Lubuntu 16.10 and I am trying to install the Elementary OS Openbox theme from this page: https://www.box-look.org/content/show.php/Elementary+OS+Openbox?content=163471

I downloaded the .obt file and tried to install it in Customize Look, but it gave me this error:[image]

Comment: Hello, whats your status? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with that theme is it doesn't respect [the file structure of an Openbox theme](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Themes#Theme_file_structure), because it should contain a top level directory with the name of the theme.

*Hint: You can use `file-roller` or other archivers to see the contents of an .obt file (it seems to be just a zip file with an obt extension).*

Anyway, I couldn't install the theme either using `lxappearance` (Customize Look). So here's what I did:

1) Open a terminal.

2) Create a directory to contain the files:

`mkdir Elementary-openbox`

3) Extract the archive files:

`unzip -d Elementary-openbox /path/to/163471-elementary-os-05102014.obt`

(replace **/path/to** with an actual path)

4) Move the theme:

`mv Elementary-openbox $HOME/.themes`

Now the theme should be installed as Elementary-openbox.

*Hint: Openbox and GTK themes are installed globally to `/usr/share/themes` and locally to `/home/{username}/.themes`. `Writing to /usr/share/themes` requires root access.*

---

## Problems with directory and its permissions

---

Additionaly, if you have any problems copying the theme files to $HOME/.themes this may be of help:

We will be using a terminal, so open one.

1. Check that the directory exists:

   `stat $HOME/.themes` <- this command will complain if a file or dir doesn't exist.

   If it doesn't exist, create it: `mkdir $HOME/.themes`
2. If the file does exist, check your permissions:

   ```
   myuser@myhost:~/some/path$ ls -al $HOME/.themes
   drwxrwxr-x  8 myuser mygroup 4096 mar  1 02:24 .
   ^           ^   ^       ^      ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
   |           |   |       |      |   |   |   |   |
   col. #1     #2  #3      #4     #5  #6  #7  #8  #9
   ```

   *Note: We only care about the line for the file whose name is the dot (.), that is the 9th column, which refers to the `$HOME/.themes` directory.*

   2.1. First, verify that you are the directory's owner (given by the third column, 'myuser' in this case), not root, not anyone else. If you are not the owner, change the directory's ownership with `sudo chown -R {username}: $HOME/.themes`.

   2.2. Now, lets verify the permissions. From the same output we checked before, the first column indicates permissions, this one may be a bit tricky to understand. I'll break it down for you:

   In my example, `ls` gave us **drwxrwxr-x**, we don't really care about the first letter **d**, it just indicates that we are dealing with a directory. Now, the next letters (**r, w, x**) we do care about, lets split them into sets of three or less, starting from the left. If you get other letters, like **s** or **t**, ignore them. If you have less than 3 letters, but they would repeat if put together, then they belong to a different set. Here's how the sets would look like:

   ```
   rwx               indicates file owner permissions
      rwx            indicates group permissions
         r-x         indicates anyone else's (other) permissions
   ```

   The **w** indicates Write permission, you should see it in the first set (file owner). If you don't, give yourself that permission issuing the following command: `chmod ug+w $HOME/.themes`.

Now you should be able to follow the first part of the instructions or use lxappearance to install other **valid** themes.

If you launch `lxappearance` as a normal user it will install themes locally. To install themes globally (for all users), launch `lxappearance` as root.